# Return only single record on codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

How can I return only 1 record on this statement?

```
public function edititem($id){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $query = $this->db->get('tblitem');
   $this->db->where('item_id',$id);

   foreach ($query->result() as $row){
        echo $row->item_id.'</br>';
        echo $row->item_name.'</br>';
        echo $row->item_description.'</br>';
        echo $row->item_price.'</br>';
   }
}
```

It gives me all the records instead

Comment: Just add `$this->db->select('column_name');` and use `->row()` to get single record

Comment: And what single value you wnat to return???

Comment: I meant single record not single value. I want to have the name, description and price of an item using its id

Comment: You have more than one item with the same id??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$this->db->limit(1);` to get 1 record only.

Answer (score 2):

For fetching single row form table use `->row()`

```
function edititem($id) {
    $this->db->select('item_id,item_name, item_description,item_price');
    $this->db->where('item_id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);// only apply if you have more than same id in your table othre wise comment this line
    $query = $this->db->get('tblitem');
    $row = $query->row();

    echo $row->item_id . '</br>';
    echo $row->item_name . '</br>';
    echo $row->item_description . '</br>';
    echo $row->item_price . '</br>';
}
```

Read https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

Use these

**Method 01** - [`$this->db->get()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=limit#selecting-data)

```
$query = $this->db->get('tblitem' ,1 , 0); # Set Limit
```

**Method 02** -  [`$this->db->limit()` in CI](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=limit#limiting-or-counting-results)

```
$this->db->limit(1);
```

**Method 03** -  [Result Rows in CI](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=query%20results#result-rows)

```
$row = $query->first_row('array');
$row = $query->last_row('array');
$row = $query->next_row('array');
$row = $query->previous_row('array');
```

These will only produce one set of data. and in your `foreach` loop it will always return one

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit`, so sql will return you **the only first** row found, but not the whole set of rows. The [CI's manual is explicit](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) about getting results.

here're two one-liner solutions, through the [get()](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=limit#selecting-data):

```
// ... other query conditions
$this->db->limit(1)->get('tblitem')->row()->your_key;

// or with the short syntax for defining limit, through the get:
$this->db->get('tblitem', 1, 0)->row()->your_key;
```

if you need to reference several values later on, assign result of row() to variable, to re-use later.

```
$row = $this->db->limit(1)->get('tblitem')->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$this->db->get()->custom_row_object(0, 'Your_Model');
```

The code above is mentioned by the codeigniter user guide. The best about this is no need to loop foreach where you can get very specific row value.